# ORA-12545 when exe is on network drive

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have a problem with a C# application that connects to Oracle with ODP.Net.

This application is stored on a network drive and cannot be stored on a local drive for architecture reasons.

When launched from the network drive by an Administrator, everything is ok. 
When launched from a local drive by a user, everything is ok. 
When launched from the network drive (on which the user has read/ write rights) by a user, an ORA-12545 is thrown.

I found on SO some problem related to that, but no solution except to have the app on a local drive.

The ORA-12545 is in this case not related to a network connection issue, so I suspect some GPO to interfere with that but I'm unable to spot it.

Anyone has any idea to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the complete version of ODP.NET you are using and whether it is the Managed Driver or unmanaged driver. Also, let us know which version of .NET you are using. Also, where is the tnsnames alias located? Is it on the network share in a config file or tnsnames.ora? Or is it on the local drive?

Comment: Thanks, the Oracle DLL are deployed with the app (oraociei11.dll and so on), so no need for tnsnames.ora. The version is 11.2.0.1 (32 bits).

Comment: You need tnsnames.ora if you are using an alias in the connect string and it is not defined in a .config file. What does your connect string look like?

Comment: The connection string is defined in the code like a tns names entry, it works well when the app is on a network drive (and it's ok when the program is launched as admin !). the entry is (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MYHOST.MYDOMAIN)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICE)))